# Is socket connection required to stream the data to the web server?

Tags: android, sockets

I am new to socket programing. I have to make an app for android which should stream video to the web. I have read about this on various website and all say to use socket.

Is socket required to do this? I mean is there any other way of doing this without socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Google, I found various methods some of which uses socket and some other not. There are also various protocols available which is specially meant for streaming purpose such as rtpm, rtsp, etc. One can also use http to do the same.